# asp.net login and register user controls formatting

Tags: asp.net

I have a VS2010 C# web application with standard login and register controls.

The login/register template is generated as below.The problem with this is that the label and the text field are displayed in 2 lines. But I would like to display them in single line with proper alignment . All label text right aligned with each other etc. I tried by CSS but I cannot assign length to inline elements. I can try converting everything to block elements and assigning width,float. But I am wondering if there is any option to generate table layout without too much CSS fiddling.

```
<p>

  <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" 
                              AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>

  <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="texdtEntry"></asp:TextBox>

 </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `Convert to Template` and change it:

[How to: Use Advanced Features of the ASP.NET Login Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178340.aspx)